# How to get symbols from a Qt application?

Tags: qt, debugging, debug-symbols

I'm facing a problem where my Qt application crashes with this ugly "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.", without any more information.

My development environment is the one here :

- Windows 7-64
- Qt 5.10.1
- qmake
- MinGW 32

For several days, I have been trying to find the root cause of the problem. To do this, I have read a lot of posts about this message, both on SO and more generally on the web, and the way to debug post-mortem. So I installed Wingdb to try to exploit a dump that I create at the time of the crash, which appears randomly and for which I have no idea of ​​the origin.

I think this process to investigate is the right one, but if I go wrong, please, lead me in the right way.

The difficulty encountered is about symbols, which I don't know how to generate when compiling (for my application) neither where to find for Qt dll (and even if there is a need for them). Without symbols, there is no possibility to access locals and to gain a hope to find the problem.

Can you tell me how to solve this ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run `qmake CONFIG+=debug` for you project. This will configure makefiles to include debug info.

If you use QtCreator you can just swith to Debug build. "Build and Run" switch button placed on the bottom-left panel with PC-like icon.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, qmake handles the symbol part for you when you do a debug build:

```
qmake "CONFIG+=debug"
mingw32-make
```

Having `"CONFIG+=debug"` will add debug symbols to your program and will also link it against debug Qt libraries which have debug symbols (`Qt5Cored.dll` in debug and `Qt5Core.dll` in release).

But you might have another issue, as far as I know, if you generate a dump in Windows, you generally end-up with a dump that is meant to be used by the MSVC debugger, not by gdb. Also mingw/gdb and MSVC do not use the same format for debug symbols and therefore you cannot mix the 2 toolchains.

The easiest way for you I think would be to use Qt Creator, the IDE that comes with Qt and use it to start your program in debug mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer you two. Problems are : I already have the Config+=debug and config+=qml_debug in qmake and I use Qt creator to debug my program. But Qt creator is over when the application crashes, even in debug mode... It's why I need to use a post-mortem debugger.

Comment: @kontiki You can configure Qt Creator  as post-mortem debugger. It is under "Tools > Options > Debugger > General > Behavior". Also if you have "CONFIG+=debug" then the symbols are here, and you are likely having issue of MSVC vs MinGW like I said before.

Comment: Thanks so much Benjamin. I activate the post-mortem option. But contrary to what is written here, http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#launching-in-post-mortem-mode, there is no button to launch Qt debugger in the error message, while the debugging tools are installed.

Comment: @kontiki That's weird. I cannot test now, but I have used it already. I think the error message in handled by Windows, so it might be that Qt Creator did not registered itself properly as a post-modern debugger. You might want to retry with QtCreator launched as Admin. Also if the process is still appearing in Windows process list, you might be able to attach Qt Creator manually "Debug > Start debugging".

Comment: I tried with Qtcreator in admin mode and attached to the process. The attachment works. But when crashing, nothing very helpful happened. What seems interesting from my previous link is the core mode for Linux and post-mortem for windows, my case. Also, you're right when talking about the issue of MSVC vs MinGW. I give up for today and want to thank you very much for your help. If anything comes back to you, let me know.